Gradle debug build fails suddenly due to inability to fetch dependencies
Until day before yesterday everything was working well. Since yesterday evening, after I cleared my gradle and android studio cache, I have not been able to build my app due to the following issues highlighted by gradle:
> FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures. 1: Task failed with an
> exception.
> > Could not find com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:2.25.0. Searched in the following locations:
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/2.25.0/dexmaker-mockito-2.25.0.pom
>        - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/2.25.0/dexmaker-mockito-2.25.0.pom
>        - https://jitpack.io/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/2.25.0/dexmaker-mockito-2.25.0.pom
>        - https://clojars.org/repo/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/2.25.0/dexmaker-mockito-2.25.0.pom
>        - https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/2.25.0/dexmaker-mockito-2.25.0.pom
>        - https://maven.google.com/com/linkedin/dexmaker/dexmaker-mockito/2.25.0/dexmaker-mockito-2.25.0.pom

Upon clicking those links, none of them open up. This is the legit link to the repo
Build output:

Like wise it fails for a lot of dependencies. I am not able to find out if its because maven is down or jitpack is down. This is impacting my dev time as i am unable to provide debug / release builds because of these failures. I initially thought it probably has something to do with my net connection so switched to mobile hotspot and tried but results were the same. Has anyone else encountered this?
Tools used:
Android Studio Koala running on gradle 7.5

Why you don't use the latest version of the library?

@ErfanSn : I did that already. But all versions are being fetched from the same domain and that is not accessible :(

Try toggling Gradle offline mode and see if you have setup some proxy

I have the same problem, 6 libraries can't be loaded from Jitpack, Android project won't build :'(

After days of trying to find out, the reason for all this chaos is because some of the libraries that I was using in the project are no longer available or supported in jitpack or maven. So I had to check if removing them had any impacts. I was able to permanently remove some libraries while I had to find the jar / aar files for others and put them into my project. Then I was able to build and run successfully.
